# How to attach multiple IAM policies to IAM roles using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform

I want to attach multiple IAM Policy ARNs to a single IAM Role.

One method is to create a new policy with privileges of all the policies (multiple policies).

But in AWS, we have some predefined IAM policies like `AmazonEC2FullAccess`, `AmazomS3FullAccess`, etc. I want to use a combination of these for my role.

I could not find a way to do so in the Terraform documentation.

As per documentation we can use [`aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html) to attach a policy to a role, but not multiple policies to a role as this is available via AWS console.

Please let me know if there is a method to do the same or is it still a feature to be added.

The Terraform version I use is `v0.9.5`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Thanks Krishna Kumar R for the hint.

A little more polished answer I reached from your answer.

```hcl
# Define policy ARNs as list
variable "iam_policy_arn" {
  description = "IAM Policy to be attached to role"
  type = "list"
}

# Then parse through the list using count
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role-policy-attachment" {
  role       = "${var.iam_role_name}"
  count      = "${length(var.iam_policy_arn)}"
  policy_arn = "${var.iam_policy_arn[count.index]}"
}
```

And finally the list of policies should be specified in *.tfvars file or in command line  using -var, for example:

`iam_policy_arn = [
"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"]`

Comment: Only downside to this is that you can't set a default value with interpolation in variables so you can't reference `arn` from a `aws_iam_policy `'s `resource` or `data`.  The default value will only take a text list.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete to me. How is the policy for e.g. AmazonEC2FullAccess brought in here?

Comment: Is there a way to check if the managed policy is already attached to the target role or not? say a check before attaching and attach only if it not already attach to the Role.

Comment: @magnus It is brought in via the `iam_policy_arn` list variable. Note that `AmazonEC2FullAccess` is an AWS *Managed* Policy - predefined by AWS HQ. :)

Comment: Using Terraform's new syntax, this would be:
`# Define policy ARNs as list
variable "iam_policy_arn" {
  description = "IAM Policy to be attached to role"
  type = list(string)
}

# Then parse through the list using count
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role-policy-attachment" {
  role       = var.iam_role_name
  count      = length(var.iam_policy_arn)
  policy_arn = var.iam_policy_arn[count.index]
}`

Answer (score 76):

For Terraform versions >= 0.12 the cleanest way to add multiple policies is probably something like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role-policy-attachment" {
  for_each = toset([
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess", 
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
  ])

  role       = var.iam_role_name
  policy_arn = each.value
}
```

As described in Pranshu Verma's answer, the list of policies can also be put into a variable.

Using `for_each` in favor of `count` has the advantage, that insertions to the list are properly recognized by terraform so that it would really only add one policy, while with count all policies after the insertion would be changed (this is described in detail in [this blog post](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9))

Comment: Note that using a variable for the list causes `plan` time errors, because TF doesn't know at the time how many items are in the list

Comment: Full error message for reference: `The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.`

Comment: @JHamm correct. This error appears in cases where the argument of for_each depends on outputs of resources (it works with variables though). In such a case, if the number of resources is known in advance, one can still list the resources one by one as in the answer of krishna_mee2004. I have not tested if using count, as in the accepted answer still works in situations where the number of resources depend on the resource output.

Comment: Indeed, `for_each` doesn't work in case there is a reference in a set. For example `for_each = toset(["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy", aws_iam_policy.handy_ecs_tasks_execution_role_iam_policy.arn])`. However, `count` works fine in this case.

Comment: to fix for_each, terraform suggests to use a one off `-target` invocation, ie `terraform apply -target aws_iam_policy.handy_ecs_tasks_execution_role_iam_policy`. `terraform apply` should work afterwards

Answer (score 34):

Did you try something like this:

```hcl
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_role_name" {
  name = "iam_role_name"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "mgd_pol_1" {
  name       = "mgd_pol_attach_name"
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role_name.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.mgd_pol_1.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "mgd_pol_2" {
  name       = "mgd_pol_attach_name"
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role_name.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.mgd_pol_2.arn}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solves my purpose, but can there be a more cleaner way to pass the ARNs as a list.

Actually I created a module in similar fashion to create a role attach multiple policies but executing it twice was overwriting previous attachments.

Comment: assume_role_policy is a required field in "aws_iam_role"

Comment: The argument "assume_role_policy" is required, but no definition was found. Not sure how you got this working?

Comment: I understood the error about assume_role_policy. You need create or get a policy_document. This terraform doc example show how do that:

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#example-of-using-data-source-for-assume-role-policy

Answer (score 2):

In my case I added multiple statements in one policy document:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns-and-sqs-policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowToPublishToSns"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sns:Publish",
    ]
    resources = [
"arn:aws:sns:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.id}:*"
    ]
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowToSubscribeFromSqs"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sqs:changeMessageVisibility*",
      "sqs:SendMessage",
      "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
      "sqs:GetQueue*",
      "sqs:DeleteMessage",
    ]
    resources = [
      data.resource.arn,
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "sns-and-sqs" {
  name   = "sns-and-sqs-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns-and-sqs-policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "sns-and-sqs-role" {
  role       = "role_name"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.sns-and-sqs.arn
}
```

simply combine your policies to multiple statements in one policy

Comment: This doesn't work specifically when one statement has  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole".  AWS replies   creating IAM Role (myrole): MalformedPolicyDocument: AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions.  For just actions, seems good.

Comment: @Randy because there is a difference between assume_role_policy and the policy in the example, 

the resources policy can be managed in the same way in the original comment  
but to manage the assume role policy is here:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#assume_role_policy

it can added directly to the aws_iam_role resource and it can't be attached.

Answer (score 2):

1.Use a datasource with for loop to get all the policies

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "management_group_policy" {
  for_each = toset(["Billing", "AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess"])
  name     = each.value
}
```

2.Attach to role as so;

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "dev_role_policy_attachment" {
  for_each   = data.aws_iam_policy.management_group_policy
  role       = aws_iam_role.role.name
  policy_arn = each.value.arn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding another option, which is similar to the excepted answer but instead of:

```
policy_arn = "${var.iam_policy_arn[count.index]}"
```

You can use the [element function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/element.html):

```
policy_arn = "${element(var.iam_policy_arn,count.index)}"
```

I think that in some cases (like a project with a large amount of code) this could be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how i did it:

```
resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "policy_attach_example" {
  for_each   = aws_iam_policy.example
  group      = aws_iam_group.example.name
  policy_arn = each.value["arn"]
}
```

So basically "aws_iam_policy.example" is a list of policies that i have made in the same way, with for_each

Hope that this help you, i know i come late but i had this simillar issue