# How to use managed policy with iam role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I am using terragrunt to call my terraform module.I have one terragrunt.hcl for my dev and another for  testing environment.I would like to be able to attach AWS Managed policy(AdministratorAccess) to my Dev account and (AmazonEC2FullAccess) to my testing account using input variable so that I can remove the policy line in my aws_iam_role_policy section

```
terragrunt.hcl

terraform {
  source = "..//module/vpc"
}


include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

inputs = {

 
} 


main.tf
resource "aws_iam_role" "GitHubActions" {
  name = var.GithubAction_role

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
    "Principal":{
      "Federated": "${aws_iam_openid_connect_provider.github_oidc_github_actions.arn}"
    }
}
EOF
}




resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "GitHubActions"{
  name = var.policy
  role = aws_iam_role.GitHubActions.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understand your question. You cannot attach an `IAM Policy` to an account. However, you can attach it to an `IAM Role` which seems to be your goal here? If yes, you can use a `data source`:

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "AmazonEC2FullAccess" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.GitHubActions.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.AmazonEC2FullAccess.arn
}
```

See [iam_role_policy_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment) and [iam policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy) data source.

Comment: do you know if the data source policy will accept a list of managed policy arn if i need to attach more than one managed policy to a role like ["arn1","arn2"] etc

Comment: Yes, you can. But then you would need to pass a list of policies, and loop through them. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486041/how-to-attach-multiple-iam-policies-to-iam-roles-using-terraform).